# Deleting part of a multidimensional array in python

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, python-3.7

I am trying to delete part of a multidimensional array. I am trying to delete X_val from X  to get X_train as shown below:

```
X=[], # where X.shape (1944,1877)
X_val=[], # X_val.shape (504,1877)
X_train =  np.delete (X, X_val, axis = 0) # X_train.shape is supposed to be (1440,1877)
```

I kept getting this error : arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) typ. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Read the `np.delete` docs carefully.  The exact nature of the `obj` argument seems to confuse a lot of people.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve X_train?

Comment: I've seen ML posts that use some sort of `split` function that produces `x_test, x_train, y_test, y_train` all in one call.   But I suspect that even that uses two complementary indexing arrays, boolean or integer.  Despite the name `delete` is really a just a  way of selecting a subset of "rows".